# How to notify user about all changes made during his absence

Tags: entity-framework, authentication, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm learning Blazor Server-side (or basically developing web-apps in general) and I came to the following problem: how to notify users about all updates made during their absence? I would like to display such information in a kind of "Cockpit" they see after logging-in.

So far I came up with the following solution:

- maintaining date field "UpdatedOn" in items database on SaveChanges()
- maintaining date field "LastActivity" in user database on logging out, quitting, etc.
- after user being logged-in again, displaying all items where UpdatedOn > LastActicity

I have the following setup:

- UserManager service with injected UserDbContext for CRUD methods (get user, approve user, update last activity etc.)
- Customized AuthenticationStateProvider (to use Session/Local Storage)
- CircuitHandler service to invoke OnCircuitClosed event to fire UpdateLastActivity method from the UserService on leaving the app

My question is if there is any preferred solution for this or a better one than above?
Should I inject CircuitHandler to the UserManager service and subscribe UpdateLastActivity method directly to its event or better solution would be to do it via Blazor Component (Main Layout for example)? Would you also use AuthenticationStateProvider directly in your logic or rather pass current user state from component's [CascadingParameter] or  context as a parameter?

Thank you!

Comment: If its about a set of information, why not just record the time they last queried the information?

Comment: Dear Brian, thank you for your answer, this indeed might be easier to implement.